# What is difference between xargs with braces and without in Linux?

Tags: linux, centos, xargs

I want to know what is the difference between this

```
ls | xargs rm
ls | xargs -i{} rm {}
```

Both are working for me

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`xargs rm` will invoke `rm` with all arguments as parameter departed with spaces.

`xargs -i{} rm {}` will invoke `rm {}` for each of the argument and `{}` will be replaced by the current argument.

If you have 2 arguments `a.txt` and `b.txt`, `xargs rm`  will call this

```
rm a.txt b.txt
```

But `xargs -i{} rm {}` will call

```
rm a.txt
rm b.txt
```

This is because `-i` option implies `-L 1` option which mean the command `rm` will take only `1` line each time. And here each line contains only 1 argument.

Check this [Ideone link](http://ideone.com/r1E5x0) to get more idea about it.

Answer (score 6):

`-i` option (equivalent to `--replace`) creates a sort of placeholder where xargs stores the input  it just received. In your second command, the placeholder is `{}`, it works like find `-exec` option. Once defined, xargs will replace this placeholder with the entire line of input. If you don’t like the `{}` name, you can define your own:

```
ls | xargs  -iPLACEHOLDER echo PLACEHOLDER
```

In your case, both commands are producing the same result. In the second form, you are just making explicit the default behaviour with the `-I` option.

Answer (score 4):

With braces it will spawn one `rm` process per file. Without the braces, `xargs` will pass as many filenames as possible to each `rm` command.

Compare

```
ls | xargs echo
```

and

```
ls | xargs -I {} echo {}
```